# C++ Using for loops when you don't know when the iteration would end

Tags: c++, c++11

So I have this code for c++ (not c++11)

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int calcTrip (string s) {
    int ans = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(s); i++) {
        char c = s[i];
        ans = ((ans*(c - 'A' + 1)) );
    }
    return ans;

}
int main() {

    string a1, a2;
    cin >> a1 >> a2;
    cout << calcTrip(a1) << endl;
    if (calcTrip(a1) != calcTrip(a2)) {
        cout << "STAY" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "GO" << endl;
    } 

}
```

For my for loop in the variable `i` in `calctrip`, if I do `i<sizeof(s)` I get `i` is less than 32 because a string has a size of 32. Since string `s` is a user input, how do I make `i` less than the number of characters in a user input, s.

P.S And I know how to do this in c++ 11, but for class, I need to know how to do it in c++ 98

Comment: `sizeof(s)` is not the length of `s` in characters. Are you sure you know what you are doing?

Comment: -> You should use `s.size()` instead.

Comment: Unless I need to glance it from the question header, I don't see a specific question in here? Seems you are missing a part of your question.

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sizeof operator returns the sizeof datatype not variable.Using sizeof(s) will return the size of string rather than size of a1...So can use ,

> `a1.size()
>     or
>   a1.length()`

to get the length of string variable.

Answer (score 4):

To iterate over an `std::string` (or over the any of [Standard Containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)) in C++98, you can use iterators too:

```
for(std::string::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it) {
    char c = *it;
    ans = ((ans * (c - 'A' + 1)));
}
```

The [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is a C++11 feature, but iterators aren't. Another option is to use a simple `for` loop as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
    char c = s[i];
    ans = ((ans * (c - 'A' + 1)));
}
```

The [`std::string::size`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/) returns the number of characters in the `std::string`.